# 'venues/explore' API call isn't returning venue photos even if venuePhotos flag is set to 1

Tags: json, foursquare

As of today the 'venues/explore' API call had stopped returning photos even if the venuePhotos parameter is set to 1 as the documentation suggests. The 'photos' array in the suggestions list is now empty. Is that a temporary issue?

Comment: I have the same issue. Why did you get downvoted?

Comment: Tweeted them. https://twitter.com/benjaminnetter/status/347732600120561664

Comment: I did the same 6 hours ago - https://twitter.com/sthoughts/status/347638769895235585

Comment: maybe we should ping @akdotcom if he's around. (Not sure this is working)

Comment: it came back to normal.

Comment: There was a regression which has since been fixed, thanks for you help identifying the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Add `reasonsDetail=1` to 'venues/explore' API call, and you will get the missing 'photos', for now (2013/6/21).

Comment: It works. Is there any reason for this changing?

Comment: Works for me as well. Will the documentation be updated anytime soon? Is that a permanent change? 

Any chance to have the same parameter working on the venues/search call? Sometimes you have to show photos along with the search results, and it's a waste to do a separate /photos call to achieve that...

Comment: Seems like the regression is happening again as of today 28th of June, 2013. Now even the `reasonsDetail=1` is not working